# Should I answer this question or should I add an answer to these other "similar" questions?

Tags: discussion, answers, exact-duplicates

I was going to answer [a question about books for time series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/254534/58675). However, in comments Andre Silva pointed out [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20514/books-for-self-studying-time-series-analysis) (which is also a Community Wiki) and [this other answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9667/learning-material-about-time-series).

Now, the latest question is slightly different because the user specifically asks for (at least) two books, the first one very theoretical and not specifically related to forecasting, and a more applied second one, targeted at forecasting. Thus, in principle, the user might not be satisfied by Andre Silva's links. However, to avoid duplicating (or nearly duplicating) questions, I was thinking of adding my answer to the Community Wiki question, and let the user know with a comment. I think that's fine, what do you say?

Comment: I provided the links to help the OP finding an answer. I think that question was a duplicate. I did not flag it as duplicate, because I've had some flags declined recently and could not understand why. If it is not a duplicate, then the OP being aware of such links, he/she can explain why it is not a dupe (if it is the case).

Comment: @AndreSilva sure, I wasn't criticising your approach, I think you did the right thing by taking the time to make a search & post the links.

Comment: At times I have done both (not on book recommendation threads but I don't see why that would be an exception.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Absolutely fine—in my opinion the best thing to do. Several threads have already been merged with [Books for self-studying time series analysis?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/20514/17230) & doubtless more will be. Questions asking for textbook recommendations are often differentiated only by rather specific, personal requirements that are barely reflected in the answers: it's best to aim for a single well-curated thread with a set of answers describing each book well, providing readers with the information to make their own decisions.